# Il fu [nome]: errato?

Tags: grammar

Sono stato corretto nel dire

> "[...] al tempo del **fu** Giovanni."

dove "fu" indica, similmente a quanto avviene nel noto titolo "Il *fu* Mattia Pascal", la persona dell'ormai defunto Giovanni. La frase non è precisamente quella, ma l'errore attribuito al significato da me "assunto" sì.

È pertanto, sia nel contesto colloquiale  che in quello scritto ("formale"), una forma accettabile?

Comment: Non ho nulla da aggiungere dal punto di vista grammaticale, ma visto che si parla di contesto formale, credo sia importante tenere in considerazione come sarà percepito dal lettore. Ad esempio, se anche fosse giusto, ma il tuo capo pensasse che fosse sbagliato, comunque non sarebbe un buon risultato per te. Se al contrario il testo fosse scritto per un lettore con una buona conoscenza letteraria gli verrà in mente, appunto, il testo di Pirandello.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il Treccani lo [registra](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fu/) senza nessuna marca d'uso del tipo “colloquiale” o simili; Pirandello, come menzioni giustamente, ne fa il titolo di un romanzo. Come si può pensare che sia errato?

Comment: Ho letto questa espressione molte volte nei romanzi di Camilleri.

Comment: Per esempio, «Il fu raggiuneri Cosimo Barletta era stato ammazzato mentri ...» (Andrea Camilleri, *Un covo di vipere*).

Comment: Direi che l'uso è  formale  e soprattutto letterario. Probabilmente al sud è rimasto come  uso colloquiale. Non  mi viene in mente però quale espressione alternativa viene comunemente usata. Forse *buon* o forse nessuna citando solo il nome della persona.

Comment: Concordo con te, @DaG: nemmeno a me sembra errato. Mi domandavo, perciò, se fosse incorretto utilizzarlo in produzioni scritte, dove il lessico e la grammatica sono più stretti, a differenza proprio di un libro dove la questione è più sciolta; spero tu capisca cosa intendo.

Comment: @Josh61: Un altro modo molto colloquiale (e che può risultare fastidioso) è “povero”: “come diceva sempre il povero Mario...” Poi ci sono “buonanima” e altri. Personalmente, uso il nome da solo, senza attributi o apposizioni, col verbo al passato se serve.

Comment: @black: Penso di capire, ma non credo proprio che Pirandello mirasse qui specificamente a un effetto informale o simili.

Comment: Secondo me, il tono di Camilleri nell'esempio citato (e altri esempi simili), non è tanto colloquiale, ma piuttosto ironico. L'origine dialettale di alcune parole è dovuto al fatto che l'autore cerca di descrivere quello che sta pensando il commissario Montalbano.

Comment: @Charo: é vero, ma credo che in questo caso la scelta de "il fu" piuttosto che "il defunto" o simili sia stata ininfluente. Quella che segue é speculazione, ma "il fu" mi *sembra* in qualche modo piú "in personaggio", piú consono al parlare siciliano con il suo amore per il passato remoto; in una storia ambientata al nord forse  sarebbe stato "il defunto ragionier Brambilla".

Answer (score 4):

"Il fu" è un corrispettivo quasi 1:1 dell'inglese "the late Joe Public".

È una variante di registro leggermente più formale (non *in*formale) di "il defunto Mario Rossi", ma è comunque una forma diffusissima e valida in quasi tutti i contesti.

Insieme a "il defunto Mario Rossi" copre il 90% dei casi che non richiedono una particolare connotazione.